# Basic query related to probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There are two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. They can only attain positive values. Which of the following is right $$I=Pr(X+Y<c_1  \cap Y<c_2)=\int_0^{c_1}Pr(Y<c_1-x)Pr(X=x)dx$$ or $$II=P(X+Y<c_1|Y<c_2)=\int_0^{c_1}Pr(Y<c_1-x)Pr(X=x)dx$$ where $c_1>c_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Forgetting about the formalities: if we read the integral as a sum, we are summing all the cases where $[Y + x< c_1] \cap [X=x]$ where $x \in (0,c_1)$.

Also, $[Y + x< c_1] \cap [X=x]$ is equivalent to $[Y + X < c_1] \cap [X=x]$, so the integral you are considering is in fact

$$P[(X+Y<c_1)  \cap (0<X<c_1)] = P[X+Y<c_1]$$

The RHS follows because $X$ and $Y$ are positive.

A minor technical point: for a continuous r.v. $X$, $P(X=x) = 0$ for any $x$, so in a formal setting, we usually write $P(X\in dx)$ when we mean to integrate over all values of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is false, even if $X$ is a discrete random variable, or even if $\Pr(X=x)$ is supposed to mean the density of $X$.

**Reason**: You forgot about the part $\{Y<c_2\}$.

The right argumentation is as follows.

$$I=\Pr(X+Y<c_1  \cap Y<c_2)=\int_0^{c_1}\Pr(Y<c_1-x\cap Y<c_2)f_X(x)\ dx=$$
$$=\int_0^{c_1}F_Y(\min(c_2,c_1-x))f_X(x)\ dx$$

where $f_X$ is the density of $X$ if it exists. If not then

$$I=\int_0^{c_1}F_Y(\min(c_2,c_1-x))\ dF_X(x).$$

The second one is false again for the same reason, since

$$II=P(X+Y<c_1|Y<c_2)=\frac{\Pr(X+Y<c_1  \cap Y<c_2)}{\Pr(Y<c_2)}=$$
$$=\frac{\int_0^{c_1}F_Y(\min(c_2,c_1-x))\ dF_X(x)}{F_Y(c_2)}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is right then? Please guide me.

Comment: @FrankMoses: I wrote down what is right,